# How to create optional List(array) of NSData objects in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I need to save pictures but Realm documentation says that it is not possible to have NSData List, let alone optioanal. How do you think, will it work if create entity what will be contain property of NDData, and make optional list of them? Somebody faced with same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create optional type of object type (`String`, `NSDate` or `NSData`), you can just declare the properties as optional, like the following:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name: String? = nil
}
```

If you want to declare a variable of optional type for `Int`, `Float` or `Double`, you should wrap the value with `RealmOptional<T>`, like the following:

```
class Person: Object {
    let age = RealmOptional<Int>()
}
```

Please see also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#optional-properties

Comment: It is not a problem to create single optional object, problem is create  List with NSData objects and making it optional. List and LinkingObjects (n/a: must be non-optional)

Comment: @DanielNesterenko `List` cannot have the objects other than a subclass of `Object`. If you'd like to hold `NSData` in the `List`, you need to use wrapper object that holds `NSData` object as single relation, then create a `List` contains that object. So this answer is correct. But `List` still cannot have optional types of the objects. We think it doesn't make sense to hold `nil` in the `List`, please provide concrete use cases why you'd like to hold `nil` in `List`